# Backup a server to a ftp server

Tags: backup, ftp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Backup linux to ftp server](https://serverfault.com/questions/15682/backup-linux-to-ftp-server)

This scenerio is pretty common, but I have a little problem. My server is old and unless I can find precompiled libs that will work. I tried to use ncftpput to copy all my files to the ftp server. It works but for some reasons the remote server end up closing the connection. I searched for information but couldn't find a way to make ncftpput reconnect itself.

The problem is that I can reconnect manually but it will start from the first file and upload everything back until it timeout again... I have know idea how I can split my backup so it doesn't consume all bandwidth I get kicked off again (thats my theory).

If there is no other solution I might do a big loop that will loop over all file and recreate a new connection for every file and send them all one by one. If there is a better cleaner solution. I'm listening.

Comment: It isn't a duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the documentation found here: http://www.ncftp.com/ncftp/doc/ncftpput.html

It appears the default is: 
"Do (do not) try to resume transfers. The default is to not try to resume (-Z)."

If you use the "-z" it sounds as if it should allow the transfer to reconnect.

Comment: Oh right I'll try that. Didn't understood that line.. I believe the default was to resume.

Comment: It doesn't reconnect but it continue where it failed if I'm not wrong.. so thats not so bad.